# Show all windows in 12.04

Tags: compiz, 12.04

I have install new Ubuntu 12.04 (clear install) but I have this issue with windows - when I wanted all windows to by shown, I just put cursor in left bottom corner as I set it up, but now, even though I set it up again in Compiz manager ->  Scale, it shows me windows only from current workspace. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ability of the scale plugin to show either all windows or all windows of a window group has been limited to the current workspace only. This was done thru changes to the scale plugin &  what happens when left clicking on a launcher icon in unity itself.

As mentioned by czifro you can try a different switcher plugin or the alt-tab switcher in unity will allow all windows of a group by setting the bias in the unity plugin > switcher options.

The scale plugin, at least thru the current 0.9.7.6 source, can be patched &  built to return the ability to pull from all workspaces, whether all windows or all windows of a window group. compiz will be updated in the near future in 12.04, patching should remain viable, time will tell.

Answer (score 6):

try using shift switcher plugin. i would post a pic but rep is to low.
**edit** ok here's a pic
[image]

Comment: Upload a picture to [imgur](http://imgur.com) and put it as a link, and someone will edit it in for you.

Comment: Well, I didn't use it for switching windows, I used it because I could see all open windows clearly. Any other switcher doesn't offers such function. I will have to reconcile with it. And when I tried the switcher you suggest, the windows began to act weirdly, so I have to stick with the default one.